# How To Get A Partial Match Between Two Columns in Integration Services and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, lookup, ssis

I'm trying to get a match between two rows which actually contains same data but have bad formatting.

I guess an example would be more clear:
Cell1=ISBED2D001
Cell2=ISBED
These two rows actually have the same *meaning* so I have to match them. But Fuzzy Lookup component doesn't seem to work this way because no matter how low the *similarity threshold* is it doesn't return the row.

I guess I can use *Script Component* for this job but I don't know any VB and with VS2005 that is the only option I have, as far as I know (or can I use C# code as a script component?).

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I can use Script Component for this job but I don't know any VB and with VS2005 that is the only option I have, as far as I know (or can I use C# code as a script component?)

If you go with scripting option, you can not use C# directly in script component in SSIS 2005. But you can  write your solution in C# and use one of the C# to VB.NET conversion tools, such as [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).